# JS - How to validate if string is a number

Tags: javascript

I try to validate various input strings. Therefore I tried to use regular expressions. Unfortunately all negativ cases match to true as well. How can I sepcify that the regular expression has to match the whole string?

```js
const regex = /(^([0-9]+(.||,)+[0-9]?)$)||(^([0-9]+)$)||(^(.||,)+[0-9]+$)/;

const testSetPositiv = ["34", "45.45", ".7867", "3434,34", ",7834", "546.", "45546,", "0"]

const testSetNegativ = ["wegrger", "3443,34erf", "3443.34erf", ",", ".", "4525tg", "1,211.23", "1.211,23"]


testSetPositiv.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(regex.test(value));
  //should always return true
})
console.log("----------------");

testSetNegativ.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(regex.test(value));
  //should always return false
})
```

---

I also tried to use `parseFloat(...)`, but it accepts for example `"5.45abc"`:

```js
const testSetPositiv = ["34", "45.45", ".7867", "3434,34", ",7834", "546.", "45546,", "0"]

const testSetNegativ = ["wegrger", "3443,34erf", "3443.34erf", ",", ".", "4525tg", "1,211.23", "1.211,23"]


testSetPositiv.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(parseFloat(value) >= -Number.MAX_VALUE)
  //should always return true

})
console.log("----------------");

testSetNegativ.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(parseFloat(value) >= -Number.MAX_VALUE)

  //should always return false
})
```

Comment: are digits with comma valid?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, should be valid in this case; e.g., "123,123" true, BUT separators shouldn't be accepted; e.g., "1.000,23" false, "1,211.23" false

Comment: are you doing this because the number values are all strings ? (the items in array with quotes will become strings). if the number values in the array did not have strings then they would be considered numbers. E.g. [4,66,"66","4"] is 2 numbers and 2 strings

Comment: yes they are all strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt` and `parseFloat` can return numbers even if the string contains letters, check snippet:

```js
const testSetNegativ = ["wegrger", "3443,34erf", "3443.34erf", ",", ".", "4525tg", "1,211.23", "1.211,23"];
testSetNegativ.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(parseFloat(value));
})
```

I suggest you to use:

- `.replace(',', '.')` to replace the commas (used in Europe as decimal separator) with the correct JavaScript decimal separator,
- Unary operator `+` to easily convert to number. (It will return `NaN` if not a number)

```js
const testSetPositiv = ["34", "45.45", ".7867", "3434,34", ",7834", "546.", "45546,", "0"]
const testSetNegativ = ["wegrger", "3443,34erf", "3443.34erf", ",", ".", "4525tg", "1,211.23", "1.211,23"];

testSetPositiv.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(+(value.replace(',', '.')) >= -Number.MAX_VALUE)
  //should always return true
})
console.log("----------------");
testSetNegativ.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(+(value.replace(',', '.')) >= -Number.MAX_VALUE)
  //should always return false
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some negative examples, which might be not covered with this approach. I updated the question with th e negative examples; e.g., `"1,211.23", "1.211,23"` should be both evaluate to false

Comment: @d4rty Are you using `,` as decimal or thousand separator? Anyway, I've updated my snippets!

Comment: No they shouldn't be accepted (false input), any kinfd of thousand separator

Comment: @d4rty If they shouldn't be accepted, why some of them are in the `testSetPositiv ` ?

Comment: Which string do you exaclty mean in the positive set?

Comment: @d4rty `"3434,34", ",7834", "45546,"` These ones!

Comment: This is the Europe style of a non integer number. It is in this cases not an thousand seperator

Comment: Ok, in general American and European style should be accepted. Therefore in my application the input `"12,11"` is the same like `"12.11"`. Furthermore, I don't accept any kind of thousand seperator; e.g., `"1.000,12"` and `"1,000.12"` are both invalid input in my app.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `regex` solution:

```js
const regex = /^(\d*[.,]?\d+|\d+[.,]?\d*)$/;

const testSetPositiv = ["34", "45.45", ".7867", "3434,34", ",7834", "546.", "45546,", "0"]

const testSetNegativ = ["wegrger", "3443,34erf", "3443.34erf", ",", ".", "4525tg", "1,211.23", "1.211,23"]



testSetPositiv.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(regex.test(value));
  //should always return true
})
console.log("----------------");

testSetNegativ.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(regex.test(value));
  //should always return false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) class to validate a string is a valid number. If it is not a valid number, it will return `NaN`

Example:

```
>Number(".23232")
0.23232
>Number(".23232abc")
NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

use isNaN , (side note "45546," should not be a number)

```
        const testsetMixed = [34, 45.45, ".7867", "wegrger", "3443,34erf", "546.", "45546,", "0"]


    testsetMixed.forEach(function(value){
       if( isNaN(value)) {
         console.log('not number');
       } else {
         console.log('number');
       }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [`isNan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) which returns true if the input string is not numeric